# Generating random Int array of random count without repeated vars

Tags: swift, xcode, random, probability, repeat

Code first generates a random between 0-8, assigning it to var n. Then a 2nd randomNumber Generator func is looped n amount of times to generate n amount of ints between 0 and 10, all having different probabilities of occurring and ultimately put into an array. What I want is for none of those 10 possible numbers to repeat, so once one is chosen it can no longer be chosen by the other n-1 times the func is run. I'm thinking a repeat-while-loop or an if-statement or something involving an index but I don't know exactly how, nor within what brackets. Thanks for any help! Some whisper this is the most challenging and intelligence demanding coding conundrum on earth. Challenge Accepted?

```
import UIKit

let n = Int(arc4random_uniform(8))

var a:Double = 0.2
var b:Double = 0.3
var c:Double = 0.2
var d:Double = 0.3
var e:Double = 0.2
var f:Double = 0.1
var g:Double = 0.2
var h:Double = 0.4
var i:Double = 0.2
var j:Double = 0.2
var k: [Int] = []

for _ in 0...n {
    func randomNumber(probabilities: [Double]) -> Int {
        let sum = probabilities.reduce(0, +)
        let rnd = sum * Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32.max)) / Double(UInt32.max)
        var accum = 0.0
        for (i, p) in probabilities.enumerated() {
            accum += p
            if rnd < accum {
                return i
            }}
        return (probabilities.count - 1)
    }
    k.append(randomNumber(probabilities: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]))
}
print(k)
```

Comment: i can tell you the psuedo code if you want OR a proper python code

Comment: Yes please!....

Comment: psuedo code.....

Comment: Your example has a problem.  Your ten numbers (a to j) only have four values among them: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4.  Once you have selected those four values then the fifth selection *must* be a repeat.  It is impossible to get up to 8 numbers with your conditions.

Comment: No because those values become the probabilities of var occurring. When ran, what comes out are ints 0-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pseudo Code -

```
1)generate a number between 1-8
    n
2)take empty array
    arr[]
3)loop from 0 to n
    1) generate a random no
        temp
    2) check if it is there in arr
            > if it is there in arr, generate another
    3) when you get a number which is not there in arr, insert it
```

This is a python code

```
import random

n = random.randint(1,8)
arr = []
print(n)
for each in range(n):
    temp = random.randint(1, 10)
    while temp in arr:
        temp = random.randint(1, 10)
        print(temp)
    arr.append(temp)
print(arr)
```

Check code example [here](https://repl.it/repls/JitteryPartialBigmouthbass)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift** version of Ankush's answer -

```
 let n = arc4random_uniform(7) + 1
 var arr: [UInt32] = []
 for _ in 0 ... n {
    var temp = arc4random_uniform(9) + 1
    while arr.contains(temp) {
        temp = arc4random_uniform(9) + 1
    }
    print(temp)
    arr.append(temp)
 }
print(arr)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it does! Can I ask why you did     arc4random_uniform(7) + 1   instead of just (8)?

Comment: Because arc4random_uniform(7) generates random number between 0 to 7

Comment: Could you help me. I dont understand how to intertwine both methods. Mine got me the new array based of probabilities but they repeated, the one you gave doesn't repeat but doesn't incorporate the probabilities